# Adding arrows to a Gantt chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows, pgfgantt

(To-the-point question at the end of the post)
I am using the following snippet to draw Gantt diagrams, taken from [this source](http://jldiaz.wikidot.com/en-tikz-example:gantt):

```
% GanttHeader setups some parameters for the rest of the diagram
% #1 Width of the diagram
% #2 Width of the space reserved for task numbers
% #3 Width of the space reserved for task names
% #4 Number of months in the diagram
% In addition to these parameters, the layout of the diagram is influenced
% by keys defined below, such as y, which changes the vertical scale
\def\GanttHeader#1#2#3#4{%
 \pgfmathparse{(#1-#2-#3)/#4}
 \tikzset{y=7mm, task number/.style={left, font=\bfseries},
     task description/.style={text width=#3,  right, draw=none,
           font=\sffamily, xshift=#2,
           minimum height=2em},
     gantt bar/.style={draw=black, fill=blue!30},
     help lines/.style={draw=black!30, dashed},
     x=\pgfmathresult pt
     }
  \def\totalmonths{#4}
  \node (Header) [task description] at (0,0) {\textbf{\large Tasks}};
  \begin{scope}[shift=($(Header.south east)$)]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#4}
      \node[above] at (\x,0) {\footnotesize\x};
 \end{scope}
}

% This macro adds a task to the diagram
% #1 Number of the task
% #2 Task's name
% #3 Starting date of the task (month's number, can be non-integer)
% #4 Task's duration in months (can be non-integer)
\def\Task#1#2#3#4{%
\node[task number] at ($(Header.west) + (0, -#1)$) {#1};
\node[task description] at (0,-#1) {#2};
\begin{scope}[shift=($(Header.south east)$)]
  \draw (0,-#1) rectangle +(\totalmonths, 1);
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\totalmonths}
    \draw[help lines] (\x,-#1) -- +(0,1);
  \filldraw[gantt bar] ($(#3, -#1+0.2)$) rectangle +(#4,0.6);
\end{scope}
}
```

And the result is excellent, I would like to stick with this method rather than using pgfgantt or other packages with which I haven't had it so easy to create a Gantt diagram, here's an exaple of a generated diagram with that snippet in the preamble:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GanttHeader{textheight}{2ex}{7cm}{7}
  \Task{1}{First task}{0.5}{2.5}
  \Task{2}{Second task}{1.5}{2}
  \Task{3}{Another one}{3}{1}
  \Task{4}{Another one}{4}{1}
  \Task{5}{Yet another one}{5}{2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My figure's caption.}
\label{fig:gantt}
\end{figure}
```

The only thing I need is to add an arrow that shows predecessors for some tasks. Let's say an arrow going from the end of task 1, to the beginning of task 4. I have tried to set identifiers for the nodes defined in the `\Task` definition but I am quite a noob with Tikz.

Sample Gantt from [the previously cited source](http://jldiaz.wikidot.com/en-tikz-example:gantt) :

[image]

How can I add arrows from the end of one rectangle to the start of another? Preferably stair-like arrows (only horizontal and vertical lines). Otherwise, a way to declare `\node`s inside the Task definition in the desired places would help a lot!

Fully working example including needed packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% GanttHeader setups some parameters for the rest of the diagram
% #1 Width of the diagram
% #2 Width of the space reserved for task numbers
% #3 Width of the space reserved for task names
% #4 Number of months in the diagram
% In addition to these parameters, the layout of the diagram is influenced
% by keys defined below, such as y, which changes the vertical scale
\def\GanttHeader#1#2#3#4{%
 \pgfmathparse{(#1-#2-#3)/#4}
 \tikzset{y=7mm, task number/.style={left, font=\bfseries},
     task description/.style={text width=#3,  right, draw=none,
           font=\sffamily, xshift=#2,
           minimum height=2em},
     gantt bar/.style={draw=black, fill=blue!30},
     help lines/.style={draw=black!30, dashed},
     x=\pgfmathresult pt
     }
  \def\totalmonths{#4}
  \node (Header) [task description] at (0,0) {\textbf{\large Tasks}};
  \begin{scope}[shift=($(Header.south east)$)]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#4}
      \node[above] at (\x,0) {\footnotesize\x};
 \end{scope}
}

% This macro adds a task to the diagram
% #1 Number of the task
% #2 Task's name
% #3 Starting date of the task (month's number, can be non-integer)
% #4 Task's duration in months (can be non-integer)
\def\Task#1#2#3#4{%
\node[task number] at ($(Header.west) + (0, -#1)$) {#1};
\node[task description] at (0,-#1) {#2};
\begin{scope}[shift=($(Header.south east)$)]
  \draw (0,-#1) rectangle +(\totalmonths, 1);
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\totalmonths}
    \draw[help lines] (\x,-#1) -- +(0,1);
  \filldraw[gantt bar] ($(#3, -#1+0.2)$) rectangle +(#4,0.6);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \GanttHeader{\textwidth}{2ex}{4cm}{7}
      \Task{1}{First task}{0.5}{2.5}
      \Task{2}{Second task}{1.5}{2}
      \Task{3}{Another one}{3}{1}
      \Task{4}{Another one}{4}{1}
      \Task{5}{Yet another one}{5}{2}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My figure's caption.}
    \label{fig:gantt}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Take a look at the `pgfgantt` package, that has macros for creating such arrows in its `ganttchart` environment.

Comment: I was thinking the same as @TorbjørnT., I didn't understand what you meant that you don't want to use `pgfgantt`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you had mentioned `pgfgantt`. Apologies.

Comment: The fact is that I'm quite happy with the shown result, I just one to add the arrows to the mix. If necessary I'll switch to pgfgantt, but I think it should be simpler to add the arrows (maybe not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify `\Task` to the following you get named coordinates at the ends of each rectangle, called `1a`,`1b`,`2a` etc. `Na` is at the left edge, `Nb` at the right edge.

```
\def\Task#1#2#3#4{%
\node[task number] at ($(Header.west) + (0, -#1)$) {#1};
\node[task description] at (0,-#1) {#2};
\begin{scope}[shift=($(Header.south east)$)]
  \draw (0,-#1) rectangle +(\totalmonths, 1);
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\totalmonths}
    \draw[help lines] (\x,-#1) -- +(0,1);
  \filldraw[gantt bar] ($(#3, -#1+0.2)$) rectangle +(#4,0.6);
  \coordinate (#1a) at (#3,-#1+0.5); % coordinate at left end of box
  \coordinate (#1b) at (#3+#4,-#1+0.5);  % coordinate at right end of box
\end{scope}
}
```

The two last lines in the `scope` are new.

I started by thinking only of the case where the boxes overlap, in which case the following macro lets you draw arrows easily.

```
\newcommand\arrowwhereboxesoverlap[3][]{%
  % #1: arrow style
  % #2: number of first task
  % #3: number of second task
  \path (#2b) ++(0.2,-0.5) coordinate (tmpa);
  \path (#3a) ++(-0.2,0) coordinate (tmpb);
  \draw [#1] (#2b) -| (tmpa) -| (tmpb) -- (#3a);
  }
```

Use e.g.

```
\startendarrow[thick,red,->]{1}{2}
```

to draw an arrow from the first to second box.

For the case where there is no overlap, such as from 2 to 4, the drawing is simpler (less corners), so you can do something like

```
\draw [blue,dashed,very thick,->] (2b) -- ++ (0.2,0) |- (4a);
```

This can of course also be wrapped in a macro, if desired.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% GanttHeader setups some parameters for the rest of the diagram
% #1 Width of the diagram
% #2 Width of the space reserved for task numbers
% #3 Width of the space reserved for task names
% #4 Number of months in the diagram
% In addition to these parameters, the layout of the diagram is influenced
% by keys defined below, such as y, which changes the vertical scale
\def\GanttHeader#1#2#3#4{%
 \pgfmathparse{(#1-#2-#3)/#4}
 \tikzset{y=7mm, task number/.style={left, font=\bfseries},
     task description/.style={text width=#3,  right, draw=none,
           font=\sffamily, xshift=#2,
           minimum height=2em},
     gantt bar/.style={draw=black, fill=blue!30},
     help lines/.style={draw=black!30, dashed},
     x=\pgfmathresult pt
     }
  \def\totalmonths{#4}
  \node (Header) [task description] at (0,0) {\textbf{\large Tasks}};
  \begin{scope}[shift=($(Header.south east)$)]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#4}
      \node[above] at (\x,0) {\footnotesize\x};
 \end{scope}
}

% This macro adds a task to the diagram
% #1 Number of the task
% #2 Task's name
% #3 Starting date of the task (month's number, can be non-integer)
% #4 Task's duration in months (can be non-integer)
\def\Task#1#2#3#4{%
\node[task number] at ($(Header.west) + (0, -#1)$) {#1};
\node[task description] at (0,-#1) {#2};
\begin{scope}[shift=($(Header.south east)$)]
  \draw (0,-#1) rectangle +(\totalmonths, 1);
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\totalmonths}
    \draw[help lines] (\x,-#1) -- +(0,1);
  \filldraw[gantt bar] ($(#3, -#1+0.2)$) rectangle +(#4,0.6);
  \coordinate (#1a) at (#3,-#1+0.5);
  \coordinate (#1b) at (#3+#4,-#1+0.5);
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand\arrowwhereboxesoverlap[3][]{%
  % #1: arrow style
  % #2: number of first task
  % #3: number of second task
  \path (#2b) ++(0.2,-0.5) coordinate (tmpa);
  \path (#3a) ++(-0.2,0) coordinate (tmpb);
  \draw [#1] (#2b) -| (tmpa) -| (tmpb) -- (#3a);
  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \GanttHeader{\textwidth}{2ex}{4cm}{7}
      \Task{1}{First task}{0.5}{2.5}
      \Task{2}{Second task}{1.5}{2}
      \Task{3}{Another one}{3}{1}
      \Task{4}{Another one}{4}{1}
      \Task{5}{Yet another one}{5}{2}

      \arrowwhereboxesoverlap[thick,red,->]{1}{2}
      \draw [blue,dashed,very thick,->] (2b) -- ++ (0.2,0) |- (4a);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My figure's caption.}
    \label{fig:gantt}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How do you feel about this? I'm using the `pgfgantt` package for the Gantt diagrams and `pdflscape` to get the landscape mode

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254} %up to 255

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
            y unit title=0.4cm,
            y unit chart=0.5cm,
            canvas/.style={fill=none, draw=black, line width=.75pt},
            vgrid,
            title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
            title left shift=.05,
            title right shift=-.05,
            title height=1,
            title/.style={fill=none},
            title label font=\bfseries,
            bar/.style={fill=barblue},
            incomplete/.style={fill=white},
            progress label text={},
            bar height=0.7,
            group right shift=0,
            group top shift=.6,
            group height=.3,
            group peaks height=.2]{1}{36}

            %labels
            \gantttitle{2014}{36}\\
            \gantttitle{Jan}{3}
            \gantttitle{Feb}{3}
            \gantttitle{Mar}{3}
            \gantttitle{Apr}{3}
            \gantttitle{May}{3}
            \gantttitle{Jun}{3}
            \gantttitle{Jul}{3}
            \gantttitle{Aug}{3}
            \gantttitle{Set}{3}
            \gantttitle{Oct}{3}
            \gantttitle{Nov}{3}
            \gantttitle{Dec}{3}\\

            % Parameter Selection
            \ganttgroup{Group 1}{2}{18}\\ %elem0
            \ganttbar[progress=0]{Bar}{2}{18}\\
            \ganttmilestone{Mileston}{18}\\\\

            % Testing equipment
            \ganttgroup{Group 2}{2}{18}\\ %elem0
            \ganttbar[progress=0]{Bar}{2}{18}\\
            \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{18}\\\\

            % Testing
            \ganttgroup{Group 3}{19}{35}\\ 
            \ganttbar[progress=0]{Bar}{19}{35}\\
            \ganttbar[progress=0]{Bar}{19}{35}\\
            \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{27}\\
            \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{35}\\

            % Algorithm Development
            \ganttgroup{Group 4}{28}{35}\\ 
            \ganttbar[progress=0]{Bar}{28}{35} \\

            %relations 
            \ganttlink{elem2}{elem6}
            \ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
            \ganttlink{elem9}{elem11}

        \end{ganttchart}
    \caption{Gantt diagram for the first year (2014)}
    \label{fig:Gantt2014}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pgfgantt example, wish I could mark two answers as valid. I find my original method a lot simpler though, even if less complete it offers just what I needed. However, thanks for this complete sample, I will sure use it when I need more complex Gantt diagrams.